# Unnest Presto column key value pair with value as array

Tags: sql, presto, unnest

I have a table and I'm querying with Presto SQL. I need to unnest a column that is a key value pair. The key is a string, the value is an array. The values of that array are key value pairs of string key and int value.

The data structure looks something like this

`{"key1":[], "key2":[], "key3":[{"nestedKey1":1, "nestedKey2":36}]}`

The issue is the "key3" in this case changes values based on the user data. "Key3" could be one of multiple values that I don't know beforehand. I don't need any keys that have a blank array as a value, just ones that have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is actually json you can parse it and process as `map` of key-values (key will be `varchar` and value can be array of json, or you can try to refine it to `array(map(varchar, integer))`, if more processing needed):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(data) AS (
 values ('{"key1":[], "key2":[], "key3":[{"nestedKey1":1, "nestedKey2":36}]}')
)

-- query
select k, arr
from(
    select cast(json_parse(data) as map(varchar, array(json))) as parsed
    from dataset
),
unnest(parsed) as t(k, arr)
where cardinality(arr) > 0;
```

Output:

| k | arr |
| --- | --- |
| key3 | [{"nestedKey1":1,"nestedKey2":36}] |

Read more:

- [JSON Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)
- [Array Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)